# HTML/CSS Whitespace breaking

Tags: html, css

I am wondering why with markup like

http://jsfiddle.net/rkEpx/

I get

[image]

As you can see, the 1st and last menu items have its link broken into 3 lines even tho theres enough space to expand. Is it possible to have the line not break unless theres really no space? If possible without setting a fixed width or using non-breaking spaces?

Comment: Works fine in Opera 11 and IE8. Might be a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&nbsp;` HTML entity or `white-space: nowrap;` CSS.
But it won't break even if there is really no space.

You can try using `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` for your `li`, `img` and / or `p`.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Mv2E/

Comment: display: inline-block; doesn't work IE7 or IE6. You would have to use *li { display: inline; } for those browsers to work.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` is not good with when I add `max-width` the text don't wrap causing the layout to break http://jsfiddle.net/2Mv2E/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 3px 0 0;
    float: left;  
    max-width: 120px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why it is behaving like that, but it seems you can fix it by floating the `p`'s as well:

```
p {
  float: left;
}
```

Depending on your browser requirements, you can also choose to just float the `p` right after the image:

```
img + p {
  float: left;
}
```